# unique hash of string

Tags: c++, md5, hash, sha1

I want to create a unique hash (16 chars long) of an arbitrary length String. Is there a good library that implements MD5 or SHA-1 for C++ with which I can achieve this? (and possibly an example of how to use it)

Comment: What you ask for is fundamentally not possible. There are more arbitarty length strings than there are 16 char length strings so _unique_ hashes are impossible. There are plenty of libraries that implement MD5 and SHA-1 algorthims but can you clarify your requirements?

Comment: It is impossible for a fixed-length hash of arbitrary-length strings to be unique.

Comment: Is it possible to enumerate the strings and construct the hash function thereafter, on-the fly? Are you looking for a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function ?

Comment: then how does MD5 work, it returns 32-digit has values but uniquely hashes arbitrary strings, or have I got that wrong?

Comment: You've got that wrong. It does a great job of mostly not having collisions for its intended domain, but consider there are an infinite number of possible input strings. (If we were to disregard physical limitations.) Look up the Pigeonhole Principle; it's clear it's not possible to uniquely take an infinite domain and place it in a finite range.

Comment: In most cases crypto-hashes are not good candidates for using in hash map and alike.

Answer (score 6):

The [Pigeonhole Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) explains why what you ask is impossible regarding uniqueness.

Comment: how does MD5 work, because it hashes arbitrary length strings to 32-digit hex values

Comment: Yes, but if you run enough strings through MD5 you'll end up with two different strings which have the same hash: http://www.google.com/search?q=md5+collision

Answer (score 1):

You need the openssl library. It has implementations of the standard crypto hashes for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

[nss](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/) provides a number of hash and cryptographic algorithms and has a more liberal license than OpenSSL.